# Installing latest cmake version using cygwin for clion

Tags: cmake, cygwin, clion

I have recently installed cmake for my Clion project, using Cygwin. Its version was 3.10 but I had some troubles with Conan packet manager, and I have been adviced to upgrade cmake to version 3.11.

As cygwin didn't provide this version, I tried to install it "by hand", but it failed. So I unistalled cmake, and tried to download it again from Cygwin.

For some reason, Cygwin only provides me version 3.6.2. I don't understand why.

However, I would like to know how to install the lastest version of cmake using Cygwin?

I am working on Windows 10.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cygwin cmake last version is 3.6.2

https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/cmake/

If you were using the 3.10, it was not the cygwin package.

If you want to use it in cygwin you have two choice:
- build it by yourself
- ask the cygwin package maintainer (but he seems not very active recently)

Comment: Yes you are right. I was actually using the default CLion cmake version.